# Download Image on Sever with Laravel doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, api, nginx, server

Download image ( with extension png for example ) on local ( using **Apache** server ) works and returns in response `header => image/png`, which is good. That's the response on local :

[image]

But on the server which  is **nginx**, it doesn't work and returns in response `header => text/html`. That's the response on server :

[image]

I'm sure that code is 100% right, I want to return image/png on the server as it returns on local.

- And That's the code 
  [Code]
  [image]
- [Rest of code]
  [image]
- [And that's the nginx configuration]
  [image]

  - Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Can you provide some of the code (ie. enough to potentially be able to reproduce the issue)?

Comment: Done in the description

Comment: What is about `types { ... }` and `default_type ...` in nginx.conf for this `location`?

Comment: nginx configuration has been added to description